# Microsoft bot framework :We are facing an issue while deploying the bot on IIS.POST to bot’s endpoint failed with HTTP status 401”

Tags: botframework

We are facing an issue while deploying the bot on IIS. It gives an error (as in telegram)

> Post to HRSurveySSLBot failed : POST to bot’s endpoint failed with
>   HTTP status 401

We are using the registered bot -  `App_ID=29eaa0ed-4b42-4055-91fa-5771025c5253` and Password.
(We are sure we have used correct pwd.)
Bot Handle – HRSurveySSLBot.

The bot works perfectly fine while deployed on Azure.

We tried two scenarios (and several other)

1. With App Id and Password
2. Without appid and password

**Bot Info**

App ID: 29eaa0ed-4b42-4055-91fa-5771025c5253
SDK Platform: Microsoft.Bot.Builder
SDK Version: 3.11.0
Active Channels: Webchat, emulator , telegram (all three tested)
Deployment Environment: Windows server 2012

**Issue Description**
Facing an issue while deploying the bot on IIS . It gives an error (as in telegram) “Post to HRSurveySSLBot failed : POST to bot’s endpoint failed with HTTP status 401

**Code Example**
(a simple bot just responding with a "Hi" to user )
In MessageController.cs--

```
public async Task Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
}
}
```

In RootDialog.cs--

```
public class RootDialog : IDialog
{
public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
return Task.CompletedTask;
}
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result)
{
var message = await result;
await context.PostAsync("Hi, Welcome to the bot !");
}
}
```

**Reproduction Steps**
Deploy the bot on Azure---works fine

Deploy the bot on IIS (under valid ssl certificate)-- doesn't work (bot doesn't respond back)

**Expected Behavior**
Deploy the bot on Azure---works fine

Deploy the bot on IIS (under valid ssl certificate)-- Should work (bot should respond back)

**Actual Results**
Deploy the bot on Azure---works fine

Deploy the bot on IIS (under valid ssl certificate)-- doesn't work (bot doesn't respond back)

Comment: Try upgrading your bot.builder package to the latest and see if that helps

Comment: Hi JasonSowers, We had used the latest one then 3.11.0.